# How to focus on newly opened tab in qutebrowser?

Tags: python, browser

If have just switched to the [qutebrowser](https://www.qutebrowser.org/) and I'm overly happy with it.

The one thing that is disturbing me is that I can't get the qutebrowser to focus on the tab that I've just opened.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Overflow is about programming, and not the right place for qutebrowser questions. See [getting help](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser#getting-help) in the qutebrowser documentation for better places to get help.

qutebrowser usually does focus newly opened tabs by default, unless you have `tabs.background` set. You might be running into [this issue](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues/3231), or it might be something different - difficult to say more without knowing what link you're opening where, and how.

Comment: I see.  <ctrl+click> opens and focusses as I want it to be. My problems arise when clicking on links with `target="_blank"` and, thus, they seem to be already recorded in the issue that you mention.